# View & control screen of broken screen android phone?

Tags: samsung, broken-screen

I have a Samsung Galaxy S8 and need to control the phone. The display is totally messed up, its flashing about 20 different colours every 5 seconds.

I can't use touch screen as I can't see what I'm doing. USB debugging is not enabled and I want to view my screen, control it, respond to texts etc until I get my screen fixed at a store.

Is this possible? I have a really important text I need to respond to and my screen has broke?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you checked with our [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info) already?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to be able to connect using a USB cable to a laptop/desktop and to use Vysor to emulate your screen. https://www.vysor.io/